# Any way to trigger creation of a list of all classes in a hierarchy in Swift 4?

Tags: swift

***Edit:** So far it looks like the answer to my question is, "You can't do that in Swift."  I currently have a solution whereby the subclass names are listed in an array and I loop around and instantiate them to trigger the process I'm describing below.  If this is the best that can be done, I'll switch it to a plist so that least it's externally defined.  Another option would be to scan a directory and load all files found, then I would just need to make sure the compiler output for certain classes is put into that directory...*

I'm looking for a way to do something that I've done in C++ a few times.  Essentially, I want to build a series of concrete classes that implement a particular protocol, and I want to those classes to automatically register themselves such that I can obtain a list of all such classes.  It's a classic Prototype pattern (see GoF book) with a twist.

Here's my approach in C++; perhaps you can give me some ideas for how to do this in Swift 4?  (This code is grossly simplified, but it should demonstrate the technique.)

```
class Base {
  private:
    static set<Base*> allClasses;
    Base(Base &);    // never defined
  protected:
    Base() {
        allClasses.put(this);
    }
  public:
    static set<Base*> getAllClasses();
    virtual Base* clone() = 0;
};
```

As you can see, every time a subclass is instantiated, a pointer to the object will be added to the static `Base::allClasses` by the base class constructor.

This means every class inherited from `Base` can follow a simple pattern and it will be registered in `Base::allClasses`.  My application can then retrieve the list of registered objects and manipulate them as required (clone new ones, call getter/setter methods, etc).

```
class Derived: public Base {
  private:
    static Derived global;     // force default constructor call
    Derived() {
        // initialize the properties...
    }
    Derived(Derived &d) {
        // whatever is needed for cloning...
    }
  public:
    virtual Derived* clone() {
        return new Derived(this);
    }
};
```

My main application can retrieve the list of objects and use it to create new objects of classes that it knows nothing about.  The base class could have a `getName()` method that the application uses to populate a menu; now the menu automatically updates when new subclasses are created with no code changes anywhere else in the application.  This is a very powerful pattern in terms of producing extensible, loosely coupled code...

I want to do something similar in Swift.  However, it looks like Swift is similar to Java, in that it has some kind of runtime loader and the subclasses in this scheme (such as `Derived`) are not loaded because they're never referenced.  And if they're not loaded, then the `global` variable never triggers the constructor call and the object isn't registered with the base class.  Breakpoints in the subclass constructor shows that it's not being invoked.

Is there a way to do the above?  My goal is to be able to add a new subclass and have the application automatically pick up the fact that the class exists without me having to edit a plist file or doing anything other than writing the code and building the app.

Thanks for reading this far — I'm sure this is a bit of a tricky question to comprehend (I've had difficulty in the past explaining it!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question; maybe it'll help someone else.

My goal is to auto initialize subclasses such that they can register with a central authority and allow the application to retrieve a list of all such classes.  As I put in my edited question, above, there doesn't appear to be a way to do this in Swift.  I have confirmed this now.

I've tried a bunch of different techniques and nothing seems to work.  My goal was to be able to add a .swift file with a class in it and rebuild, and have everything automagically know about the new class.  I will be doing this a little differently, though.

I now plan to put all subclasses that need to be initialized this way into a particular directory in my application bundle, then my AppDelegate (or similar class) will be responsible for invoking a method that scans the directory using the filenames as the class names, and instantiating each one, thus building the list of "registered" subclasses.

When I have this working, I'll come back and post the code here (or in a GitHub project and link to it).

Answer (score 0):

Same boat. So far the solution I've found is to list classes manually, but not as an array of strings (which is error-prone). An a array of classes such as this does the job:

```
class AClass {
    class var subclasses: [AClass.Type] {
        return [BClass.self, CClass.self, DClass.self]
    }
}
```

As a bonus, this approach allows me to handle *trees* of classes, simply by overriding `subclasses` in each subclass.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I've had to put this app on hold while I finish other business, but I'll get back to it in the coming days.  Right now I'm doing the same thing you've posited here, but only because I don't yet understand how Bundles work.  Baby steps, y'know. :)